# Change flat rate shipping rate based on item cart totals belonging to specific shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to implement shipping rates according to line item totals for products belonging to a specific shipping class. The rates should work for all enabled countries.

**Shipping class:** "flat_rate:1"

**Shipping rates:**

```
+------------------+---------------+
|  Product Total   | Shipping Rate |
+------------------+---------------+
| $50 to $150      | $190          |
| $151 to $300     | $190          |
| $301 to $700     | $255          |
| $701 to $1,000   | $305          |
| $1,001 to $2,000 | $400          |
| $2,001 to $4,000 | $430          |
| $4,001 to $6,000 | $530          |
+------------------+---------------+
```

So far I have seen shipping rate codes based on either cart total/quantity, country, shipping class but not shipping class+included product totals. Only paid plugins have this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I have made, I know it can be optimized and I welcome recommendations. Thanks to [@LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) as I referenced a lot of his answers across SO to create this solution. ***Tested & works on WC 3.5.2 & WP 5.0.1***

```
/* Changes "flat rate" shipping method rates if shipping class "industrial curtains" is present in the cart */
function change_shipping_method_rate_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    /* HERE define your shipping class to find */
    $class = array(208);

    /* HERE define the shipping method to change rates for */
    $method_id1 = 'flat_rate:1';

    /* Checking in cart items */
    $found = false;
    $item_price = $item_qty = 0;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $item_shipping_class_id = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();

        if( in_array( $item_shipping_class_id, $class ) ){
            $found = true;  /* Target shipping class found */
            $item_price += $cart_item['data']->get_price(); /* Sum line item prices that have target shipping class */
            $item_qty += $cart_item['quantity']; /* Sum line item prices that have target shipping class */
            $item_total = $item_price * $item_qty; /* Get total for all products with same shipping class (There might be a better way to get this total) */
        } 
    }

    if( $found ) {
        if( $item_total > 0 && $item_total < 301 ) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 190;
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 300 && $item_total < 701) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 255;
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 700 && $item_total < 1001) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 305;
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 1000 && $item_total < 2001) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 400;
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 2000 && $item_total < 4001) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 430;
        }
        elseif ( $item_total > 4000 ) {
            $rates[$method_id1]->cost = 530;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_method_rate_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Very good code! And how would I do the same but with two different shipping classes? That is, class "208" and change the prices of 'flat_rate: 1' as in your example and class "209" and change the prices of 'flat_rate: 2' @LoicTheAztec

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, and off the top of my head, add the new shipping class to the array: `$class = array(208, 209);` remove the `$method_id1 = 'flat_rate:1';` line and then just after `if( in_array( $item_shipping_class_id, $class ) ){` line add following lines `if( $item_shipping_class_id == $class[0] ){$method_id1 = 'flat_rate:1';} else {$method_id1 = 'flat_rate:2';}`