# Hide Shipping Method conditionally based on Shipping Class, Cart Quantity and Cart Total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, operators, conditional-operator, shipping-method

I am encountering some issues with my condition to check for cart total, amongst cart quantity and shipping classes.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am trying to hide a specific shipping method `free_shipping:7` based on quantity of other specific shipping classes and cart total.

The problem I am encountering is that my conditional logic won't work after using `||` (or) operator, it will not check for cart total, if I also check for quantity.

**The code**

```
/* Hide free shipping unless minimum of 6 bottle or 1 box is selected, or if 2 gins and under 600 cart total */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_free_shipping_method', 10, 2 );
function hide_free_shipping_method( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Shipping class to check for
    $class1 = 132; // shipping class for bottles
    $class2 = 131; // shipping class for boxes
    $class3 = 142; // shipping class for gin bottles

    // Shipping method to hide
    $ShipMethod_key_ids = array('free_shipping:7'); // free shipping

    // Get cart total of items in the cart, but after discounts. 
    $cart_totals =  WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Keep track of the quantity of items with the specified shipping class
    $quantity_bottle = 0;
    $quantity_gin = 0;
    $quantity_box = 0;

    // Loop through cart content and add to specified shipping classes
    if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class1 || $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class3){
        $quantity_bottle += $item['quantity'];
        $quantity_gin += $item['quantity'];
    }
    elseif (  $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class2 ) {
        $quantity_box += $item['quantity'];
    }
}

    // If there are less than 6 bottles, 6 gins, and less than 1 box
    // or 
    // if equal to 2 gins and less than 600 in Cart Total, hide the shipping method
    if( $quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1 || $quantity_gin == 2 && $cart_totals < 600 ) {
        foreach( $ShipMethod_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

**Problem**

The problem I have is that the condition which checks for cart total, does not work when combined with `||` (or) operators.

```
if( $quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1 || $quantity_gin == 2 && $cart_totals < 600 ) {
```

If I use the combined example, as above, the code will neglect the last condition (2).

The condition will only work with one of the two:

1. `$quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1`
2. `$quantity_gin == 2 && $cart_totals < 600`

**What I have tried**

I have tried isolating the two conditions to check if they work. They do work on their own, but not in combination.

I have also tried to write them in separate `if` statements, but without any results.

**Question**

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong in this example? and what can I do to make it check for both statements?

Is it possible for me to achieve above without having to implement two different codes for each logic?

**List of references**

[how to check the quantity of products in the woocommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75071712/how-to-check-the-quantity-of-products-in-the-woocommerce-cart)

[Change flat rate shipping rate based on item cart totals belonging to specific shipping class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823663/change-flat-rate-shipping-rate-based-on-item-cart-totals-belonging-to-specific-s)

[Conditionally Hide WooCommerce Shipping methods based on shipping class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372499/conditionally-hide-woocommerce-shipping-methods-based-on-shipping-class)

[Logical Operators - php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

[WC_Cart - WooCommerce Code Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html)

Comment: you need to use parentheses to group the conditions correctly: if (($quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1) ||  ($quantity_gin == 2 && $cart_totals < 600)) {}

Comment: As for the explanation when we do complex logical expression the && operator has higher precedence than ||. Using parentheses we tell that we expect one of the conditions should return true.

Comment: Hi @Snuffy, thank you for taking your time. I tried your solution, but it didn't change much to anything. I then did some research here on stackoverflow, tried replacing `||` to `&&` and rethinking my condition, and suddenly some results. 
I also had to add extra variable to my code for the new condition to work.
`($quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1 $total_bottle_quantity_cart < 6) && !($quantity_gin >= 2 && $subtotaltax > 600 )`
I read that `&&` has higher precedence than `||` so the extra parentheses are implied and unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the major issue was with my logical expression. When we use `||` (OR), it will return true if either `$a or $b` is true. Whereas if we use `&&` (AND) it will return true if both `$a and $b` are true.

I also made sure to loop through cart items checking for shipping classes and add to the variables separately. This made my first expression invalid `$quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1`, but was needed for my second expression `$quantity_gin == 2 && $cart_totals < 600`. In order to make my first expression work, I add a new variable which counts bottle quantity and gin bottle quantity total.

```
// Loop through cart content and add to specified shipping classes
foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
    if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class1 ){
        $quantity_bottle += $item['quantity'];
    }
    if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class3){
        $quantity_gin += $item['quantity'];
    }
    elseif (  $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class2 ) {
        $quantity_box += $item['quantity'];
    }
}
// Variable counting gin and other bottles
$total_bottle_quantity_cart = $quantity_gin + $quantity_bottle;
```

So the condition ended up being: `if (($quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1 && $total_bottle_quantity_cart < 6 ) && !($quantity_gin >= 2  && $subtotaltax > 600 ) )`

The full code below:

```
/* Hide free shipping unless minimum of 6 bottle or 1 box is selected, or if 2 gins and under 600 cart total */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_free_shipping_method', 10, 2 );
function hide_free_shipping_method( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    // Shipping class to check for
    $class1 = 132; // shipping class for bottles
    $class2 = 131; // shipping class for boxes
    $class3 = 142; // shipping class for gin bottles

    // Shipping method to hide
    $ShipMethod_key_ids = array('free_shipping:7'); // free shipping
    // Get cart subtotal of items in the cart incl. tax, as a number
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal(); // Get cart subtotal value
    $subtax = WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax(); // Get cart subtotal value tax
    $subtotaltax = $subtotal+$subtax; // calculate cart subtotal value with the tax added
  
    // Keep track of the quantity of items with the specified shipping class
    $quantity_bottle = 0;
    $quantity_gin = 0;
    $quantity_box = 0;
  
    // Loop through cart content and add to specified shipping classes
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class1 ){
            $quantity_bottle += $item['quantity'];
        }
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class3){
            $quantity_gin += $item['quantity'];
        }
        elseif (  $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class2 ) {
            $quantity_box += $item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    // Variable counting gin and other bottles
    $total_bottle_quantity_cart = $quantity_gin + $quantity_bottle;
  
    // If there are less than 6 bottles, 6 gins, 1 box and less than 6 total bottles
    // or 
    // if gin quantity is not bigger than or equal to 2 and subtotal less than 600 
    // hide the shipping method
    if (($quantity_bottle < 6 && $quantity_gin < 6 && $quantity_box < 1 && $total_bottle_quantity_cart < 6 ) && !($quantity_gin >= 2  && $subtotaltax > 600 ) ) {
        foreach( $ShipMethod_key_ids as $method_key_id ){ 
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```